# how setup facebook iframe into autoresize?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-iframe, facebook-canvas

I build aplication on my server and currently have it set to display the app within the Facebook iframe.
My application is in responsive layout. Becouse display on iframe/canvas on facebook aplication, responsive not working.
How we can make iframe/canvas of facebook app in autosize so my aplication display on app can work responsive?

Thanks

Comment: will you give code jsfiddle...

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow/